# I've tried this little group of code several times, but I haven't managed to get it to work

Tags: batch-file

I think I know where the problem is, but not what it is. I isolated it to one line, but that doesn't mean it's the right one.

```
:CreateProtocol1
cls
echo.
echo How many sides should die %DieCount% have?
echo.
set /p NumberOfSides=/
if %NumberOfSides% gtr 0 (echo set NumberOfSides%DieCount%=%NumberOfSides%) >> Temp.bat
if %NumberOfSides% leq 0 set ErrorMessage=InvalidProtocolCP1
if %NumberOfSides% leq 0 goto ErrorHandler
:CreateProtocol2
cls
echo.
echo How many times should die %DieCount% be rolled?
echo.
set /p NumberOfRolls=/
if %NumberOfRolls% gtr 0 (echo set NumberOfRolls%DieCount%=%NumberOfRolls%) >> Temp.bat
if %NumberOfRolls% leq 0 set ErrorMessage=InvalidProtocolCP2
if %NumberOfRolls% leq 0 goto ErrorHandler
if %DieCount% equ %NumberOfDice% goto RunProtocol
if %NumberOfRolls% gtr 0 set /a DieCount +=1 (<< This seems to be the problem line)
goto CreateProtocol1
```

This code is meant to roll various amounts of dice for any reason. This is not the full code, just the part that's giving me trouble right now. It says something about "Protocols" before immediately closing so I can't read the rest of the error, usual batch stuff. Even more strangely, it only misbehaves on that line when it's the last "die," if I'm rolling 5, it acts up on the 5th. If I do 9, it acts up on the 9th. Since it rolls all at once, that means I can't see any of the ones I roll. So my question is, what am I doing wrong, and how can I correct it?

Comment: Remove or comment out any `@ECHO OFF` then open a Command Prompt window and run your batch file from within it. Your messages will be visible in the window so you can read them and copy them here!

Comment: Thanks, but I actually fixed it in the time it took to get a reply, heh. Thanks a lot, though! It works great.